# How to draw moving averages on Kibana dashboard?

Tags: kibana

I would like to know that is there any way (or workaround) to draw moving average on Kibana dashboard?

I have read all the documents on the official site and nothing about moving average (or advanced charts) are mentioned.

Any information or keywords will be helpful, thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Histogram Panel with Chart Value as **mean**, select your preferred **Value Field** (i.e. the field on which you want to get the average), set Chart to **Lines** and then set **Auto-Refresh** to your preferred interval:

[image]

Then you will get something like that:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I want to get the average on the number of events instead of some value of an event, how should I set the value_field property? Should I use the count query on the panel first?

Comment: Doesnt this just give you the average for a particular time frame?  In this case, its Response time per 10m, not really the moving average...  Or am I misreading this?

Comment: @Justin, it's not 'moving' average. Moving average will take the average on the values of previous n events to produce a point. For example, I have the list: [6, 5, 4, 5, 3] and its 3-item moving average is [5, 14/3, 4], 4-item MA is [5, 17/4].

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was thinking along the lines of "What is the average up to this point?" as the moving average.  I'm not a statistician and don't know the proper term for this.  Any pointers?

Comment: Here is the documentation for calculating the moving average in Elastic Search: [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-pipeline-movavg-aggregation.html] I wonder if this can be solved by displaying in Kibana an scripted field using this type of aggregation?

Comment: Oooopss! Moving averages will be introduced in Elastic Search 2.0.0 and as an experimental feature... So, no use for now (current is 1.7.0)